# blocking asp.net button postback until the web service finishes executing

Tags: asp.net, jquery

enter code hereI have an asp.net button on my webpage,on button click I do some validations on the client and return true or false based on the validation result to stop button execution(postback).

All this seems to work fine as I can see in my client code through firebug that the client code returns true or false. Now I get into a condition during client validation where I need to make a webservice call and only after the webservice call has finished I should return true from my client code for the postback to happen(I have used setinterval on the client to block to wait until the webservice call returns). But this doesn't seems to be working and postback happens before setinterval gets a chance to return true.
Below is my client code

```
function ClearUnsavedCacheBeforeSubmitting() {
    if (CalculateUnsavedChanges() && FormatStringBooleanValue(pageAlreadyChanged)) {
        if (confirm('You have unsaved changes. Click ok to proceed without saving or   cancel to stay on the page')) {
            ClearCacheNotSaved();
            var alertTimer;
            alertTimer = setInterval(function () {
                if (cacheClearedFromClient) {
                    clearInterval(alertTimer);
                    cacheClearedFromClient = false;
                    return true;
                }
            }, 100);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (!FormatStringBooleanValue(pageAlreadyChanged)) {
        alert('You do not have saved changes to submit');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

code for webservice call. This webservice works fine, gets called in other places also.

```
function ClearCacheNotSaved() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: '{"culture" : ' + JSON.stringify(selectedCulture) + ', "affiliate" : ' + 0 + ', "userName": ' + JSON.stringify(username) + ', "pageName": ' + JSON.stringify(selectedPage) + ', "adviceCenterFilesChanged": ' + JSON.stringify(adviceCenterFilesChanged) + ', "topicCenterFilesChanged" : ' + JSON.stringify(topicCenterFilesChanged) + ', "resourceUploaded" : ' + JSON.stringify(resourceUploaded) + '}',
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'WebServices/ContentManagementService.asmx/DiscardChangesFromCacheAndRepopulate',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        cacheClearedFromClient = true;
        var test = result.d != null ? result.d : result;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }        
});
```

}

Comment: Can you show `FormatStringBooleanValue()` code or your webservice call function implementation

Comment: FormatStringBooleanValue works fine it just converts string representation of true or false to boolean equivalent. ClearCacheNotSaved() is the webservice call which sets the value of cacheClearedFromClient to true so as to come out of setinterval and return true

Comment: and what about `CalculateUnsavedChanges()` code?

Comment: the code comes inside the confirm block and when you say oke on it it calls the webservice ClearCacheNotSaved().

Comment: Ok I need code of this function to carried out changes.

Comment: Have you tried removing the interval (you can never get the time right anyway) and then call `ClearCacheNotSaved()` and return `true` on `success` and `false` on error?

Comment: Ted..the webservice call is async and i need a way to know that it has finished(error or not) and then only return from there.